# redhat 6 to 8 migration procedure

Tags: migration, redhat

Is it possible to migrate a Linux RHEL 6 to 8? without going through a fresh install.
Same question for a transition from RHEL 6 to 7.
And I assume that the applications already installed are compatible with the target version

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to start with fresh install. During upgrade you may reach a lot of problems, orphan packages and files, discrepancies. But you can check [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.4/html/installation_guide/rhel6_to_rhel7) how to upgrade from RHEL 6 to 7:

Install migration tool

```
yum install redhat-upgrade-tool
yum install yum-utils
```

Disable all repositories

```
yum-config-manager --disable \*
```

Download latest RHEL 7 ISO
Upgrade to RHEL 7 using ISO

```
redhat-upgrade-tool --iso RHEL7_ISO_filepath --cleanup-post
reboot
```

Similar for 7 to 8 [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.4/html/installation_guide/rhel6_to_rhel7)